# Remapping both Caps Lock and Shift+Caps Lock in xkb

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb

I am trying to configure xkb such that Caps Lock is mapped to the Compose key and Shift+Caps Lock functions as the traditional Caps Lock.  I put the following in a new file called `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/gdwatson`:

```
partial modifier keys
xkb_symbols "compose" {
    key <CAPS> {
        type[Group1] = "TWO_LEVEL",
        symbols[Group1] = [ Multi_key, Caps_Lock ]
    };
};
```

Then I ran `setxkbmap -symbols 'pc+us+gdwatson(compose)'`, which completed successfully.  Caps Lock works as Compose, but Shift+Caps Lock works as Compose instead of Caps Lock.  `xkbcomp :0.0` reveals the following:

```
key <CAPS> {
    type= "TWO_LEVEL",
    symbols[Group1]= [       Multi_key,       Multi_key ]
};
```

The second level symbol mapping is duplicating the first for some reason, rather than the separate value I tried to give it.  Does anyone have strong enough xkb-fu to tell me what I've done wrong or how to fix it?

Comment: I can help you doing this in Xmodmap, but not xkb. If you want this, respond positively (do not forget to write `@mirabilos` in your response so I notice it) in a comment, then I will delete this comment and write it as an answer (you should then also delete your comment response).

Comment: On your first line, should `partial modifier keys` actually be `partial modifier_keys`? Without this change, `setxkbmap -symbols 'pc+us+gdwatson(compose)'` actually exits with an error, but with the change, I get the desired output from `xkbcomp :0.0`. *However* I get the undesired side-effect that pressing Capslock simultaneously puts me in Capslock mode and compose key mode.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This seems to accomplish what you're looking for.

```
partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "compose" {
    key <CAPS> {
        type[Group1] = "TWO_LEVEL",
        symbols[Group1] = [ Multi_key, Caps_Lock ],
        actions[Group1] = [ NoAction(), LockMods(modifiers=Lock) ]
    };
};
```

The following resources are invaluable when dealing with XKB (I've linked to the WayBack Machine's mirrors of these pages for future-proofing):

- Doug Palmer's [An Unreliable Guide to XKB Configuration](https://web.archive.org/web/20130211013652/http://www.charvolant.org/~doug/xkb/html/xkb.html)
- Ivan Pascal's [Notes on the X keyboard extension](https://web.archive.org/web/20020102123728/http://www.tsu.ru/~pascal/en/xkb/)

Comment: Also, if you make the first line `default partial modifier_keys`, then you don't have to explicitly specify `setxkbmap -symbols 'pc+us+gdwatson(compose)'`, you can simply do `setxkbmap -symbols 'pc+us+gdwatson'`