# How to map Caps Lock as the compose key using Xmodmap portably and idempotently?

Tags: xmodmap

I can't seem to find a way to use <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> as the compose key properly. Some methods are not portable since they require that you detect the key number using something like `xev` on every host. Other methods result in a `~/.Xmodmap` which cannot be passed to `xmodmap` more than once without [`bad keysym`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23491/how-to-change-capslock-key-to-produce-a) and similar errors. This makes it difficult to test changes to the file. Is there some way to do this in `~/.Xmodmap`?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90089/remapping-both-caps-lock-and-shiftcaps-lock-in-xkb

Comment: How portable do you need to be? With xmodmap, you can be portable to all PCs and idempotent, or portable to hardware that's pretty exotic nowadays but non-idempotent.

Comment: All solutions to this that I've encountered were *not* idempotent on Arch Linux. That is, running `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` repeatedly results in errors. I'm sure it's *possible* to be idempotent with `xmodmap`, it just doesn't seem at all obvious how to achieve this.

Comment: @l0b0 Try running `setxkbmap` to clear the keyboard map between runs to make it idempotent.

Comment: @IstvanChung How do you "clear" it? Just running `setxkbmap` doesn't do it.

Comment: On my system at least, running `setxkbmap` restores the modifier map to the state before `Xmodmap` was run.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are having problems with idempotency because you are using `keysym` instead of `keycode`. Think of `keycode` as being an assignment of a key to a function, while `keysym` is just a link from a function name to an actual function.

When you use keysym as follows:

`keysym Caps_Lock = Multi_key`

you essentially delete the name `Caps_Lock`. Therefore, the next time you run `xmodmap` and you reference `Caps_Lock` in this same line, it gets confused.

The correct way to do it is to reassign the keycode directly as follows:

`keycode 66 = Multi_key`

You can get the keycode from the `xev` command for example.

Comment: How can it ever be portable if I have to get the key code from `xev`? Also, [my `keysym` command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109441/3645) works idempotently on one machine I'm using.

Comment: It is portable as this `66` as long as you use the `evdev`driver in Xorg. In this case,  the value is defined at `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes`. How portable do you need your solution to be? What OSes, what keyboards, etc? If you just use regular USB keyboards on Linux it seems that this solution is portable.

Comment: So far it has to be compatible with at least a laptop and three desktops, all with different keyboards and with Arch Linux, Fedora and Red Hat.

Comment: So this works. All Linux and standard keyboards.

Comment: Alright, I'll try it. It would be very helpful if the answer enumerated the compatible *nixes, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

[This .Xmodmap](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/e356cd635dee9272fe6e6ebf8d512e64a0859b5e/.Xmodmap) works idempotently:

```
! Use Caps Lock button for compose key
keysym Caps_Lock = Multi_key Caps_Lock

! Remove shift lock functionality
clear Lock
```

After [logging in](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/b04ca67ff17b35e2386c52e4a5d474eb335914d6/.xinitrc#L31-L32) <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> works as the compose key. After running `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` manually it still works, and there are no error messages.

Unfortunately it's not portable:

```
$ xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
xmodmap:  /home/username/.Xmodmap:2:  bad keysym target keysym 'Caps_Lock', no corresponding keycodes
xmodmap:  1 error encountered, aborting.
```

Comment: I'm using `keycode 66 Multi_Key` and it seems to work for me. I read your other comments and am curious: Is the keycode for CapsLock really different on one of your machines?

Comment: There's a typo: it's `Multi_key` not `Multi_Key`. Lower-case `k`.

Comment: It seems that it is also not durable.  I just tried this on a fresh Fedora install, and while harmless, it was also ineffective.