# How can I autoload xkb customisations in GNOME?

Tags: gnome3, xkb

Following up on [my question about customising key mappings in Wayland](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292868/how-to-customise-keyboard-mappings-with-wayland) I've found out that `xmodmap` is apparently deprecated, but xkb "should work" in Wayland. Unfortunately, xkb is much more complicated and correspondingly more poorly documented. I've managed to work out the stanzas I need based on information from [a question about swapping <kbd>Cmd</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>](https://askubuntu.com/questions/501659/how-to-swap-command-and-control-keys-with-xkb-step-by-step), [another caps lock question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90089/remapping-both-caps-lock-and-shiftcaps-lock-in-xkb), reading some of the links in the answers and from my system files, but I don't know how to apply them in a way that can be automated and not conflict with GNOME.

These are the stanzas I've worked out, and tested successfully with `xkbcomp`.

```
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "pound" {
    // Put sterling on RAlt-3 and numbersign on Shift-3.
    key <AE03> { [ 3, numbersign, sterling, threesuperior ] };
};

// Make right cmd key act as ctrl
partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "rcmdctrl" {
    key <RWIN> { [ Control_R ] };
    modifier_map Control { <LCTL>, <RWIN> };
    modifier_map Mod4 { <LWIN> };
};

partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "shiftcaps" {
    key <CAPS> {
        type[Group1] = "TWO_LEVEL",
        symbols[Group1] = [ VoidSymbol, Caps_Lock ],
        actions[Group1] = [ NoAction(), LockMods(modifiers=Lock) ]
    };
};
```

I put the first two in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/macbook` and the third in `shiftcaps` in the same directory, and with `xkbcomp` etc they work when loaded on top of the standard `gb(mac)` layout.

I'm editing this to make an update and clarify my answer. My pound customisation recently stopped working so I checked what had changed in gb(mac) and realised I had to add `, threesuperior` to the `key <AE03>` line.

I think `evdev.xml` is used by gnome-tweak-tool to make these options available in the GUI. Here is what I added:

```
<group allowMultipleSelection="true">
  <configItem>
    <name>macbook</name>
    <description>Macbook customisations</description>
  </configItem>
  <option>
    <configItem>
      <name>macbook:pound</name>
      <description>Hash on Shift-3, Sterling on AltGr-3</description>
    </configItem>
  </option>
  <option>
    <configItem>
      <name>macbook:rcmdctrl</name>
      <description>Right Cmd key acts as Ctrl</description>
    </configItem>
  </option>
</group>
<group allowMultipleSelection="false">
  <configItem>
    <name>shiftcaps</name>
    <description>Caps Lock with Shift</description>
  </configItem>
  <option>
    <configItem>
      <name>shiftcaps:shiftcaps</name>
      <description>Caps Lock requires Shift to toggle</description>
    </configItem>
  </option>
</group>
```

Comment: gnome should see your options (and honor the `dconf` key values under `org.gnome.desktop.input-sources`) as long as you add them to the xkb rules your system is using, i.e. to the right files, see my post [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/212573)

Comment: Thanks. Defining options in the evdev files was the missing piece of the puzzle, and I've got it to do what I want now, using dconf-editor.

Comment: On my system (Debian) I also found `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml`. I'm not sure what it's for; the GNOME settings app would crash when opening the Keyboard options if I made a syntax error in it, but I can't actually find the options in the GUI. I added appropriate lines after the line containing `<optionList>`. I can't post them here because of limitations on comments.

Comment: Allow me to add that xmodmap was deprecated in around 1996 when XKB came up. I.e. years before the invention of wayland.

Answer (score 5):

don_crissti's answer to [the other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212573/how-can-i-make-backspace-act-as-escape-using-setxkbmap) provided the missing piece of the puzzle. I've defined options in the evdev files as described and added them to the `org.gnome.desktop.input-sources.xkb-options` gsetting. It works perfectly.

Comment: could you please explain how exactly you added them to this setting?!

Comment: The easiest way is with the GNOME tweaks tool. Make sure you also edit `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml` as described [here](https://realh.co.uk/wp/linux-keymap-hacking/). Then open GNOME tweaks and go to Keyboard & Mouse > Additional Layout Options. The new sections should show up there.

Comment: So basically do what on the CLI can be done with `localectl set-x11-keymap ...` on modern Linux systems?