# In bash vi mode, map jk to exit insert mode

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, vi

I'm using a fresh install of ubuntu 16.04, with the bash shell. There are two things that I want to do:

1. Set up vi mode so I can have vim-like movements from the terminal
2. exit insert mode by typing `jk`

I read in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839006/map-jj-to-esc-in-inputrc-readline) how this can be done with `zsh`, how can I do it with `bash`?

tl;dr

put `bind '"jk":vi-movement-mode'` into your `.bashrc` file after `set -o vi` :)

```
server@thinkpad:~$ tail -n 2 .bashrc
set -o vi
bind '"jk":vi-movement-mode'
```

please see @grochmal's answer for a more detailed explanation

Comment: What do you mean by remapping to `jk` ?  Is that some special key on your keyboard?

Comment: please see edit

Comment: For your first, `.bashrc` is typically called on every shell (eg if you shell out of `vi`) but `.bash_profile` is only called on login shells.  So `.bashrc` is the right place for `set -o vi`.  I don't have an answer for your revised 2nd question :-(

Comment: How are you starting your bash shell? Here is a good explanation of the [Difference between .bashrc and .bash_profile](http://superuser.com/a/183980/436955)

Comment: `set -o vi` goes in `.bashrc`, see [Why doesn't my ~/.bash_profile work?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88106/why-doesnt-my-bash-profile-work)

Comment: I'm not sure if you can have ambiguous mappings in bash. This is vi mode, not vim mode.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Bash has a similar functionality to `zsh`'s `bindkey` through `bind`, but it does not have several `vi` modes like `zsh`.  After `set -o vi` you can do:

```
bind '"jk":vi-movement-mode'
```

which is the equivalent of `zsh`'s `bindkey -M <all vi modes> jk vi-movement-mode`

The `vi-movement-mode` functions comes from `inputrc` (see `/etc/inputrc` for a list of them).

#### Full text

As Stephen Harris points out in his comment:

- `.bashrc` is called by `bash` always (and notably not by other shells).
- `.bash_profile` is only called on login shells (and again, bash only).

Several distros come with a `.bash_profile` skeleton that looks as follows:

```
# ~/.bash_profile
[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc
```

Which is a good content for `.bash_profile` since you can simply forget it exists.

Now, to map <kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> to <kbd>Esc</kbd> in the shell session, that is not really possible.  When you do:

```
inoremap jk <esc>
```

In Vim, after you type <kbd>j</kbd>, Vim knows it needs to wait a little bit to see if you type <kbd>k</kbd> next and it should invoke the mapping (or that you type another key and the mapping should not be triggered).  As an addendum this is controlled by `:set timeoutlen=<miliseconds>` in Vim (see `:h timeoutlen`).

Several shell's or X11 has no such timeout control and does not allow for multiple character mappings.  Only a mapping of a single key is allowed (But see the support notes below.) .

```
set -o vi
```

Does not read `.vimrc`, it only imitates some `vi` (not even `vim`) key combinations that can be used in the shell.  The same can be said about `-o emacs`, it does not come with the full power of `emacs`.

---

#### zsh support

`zsh` actually supports map timeout.  And you can use the following to map `jk` to `<esc>`:

```
bindkey -v  # instead of set -o vi
bindkey -e jk \\e
```

(That will need to go to `~/.zshrc` not `~/.bashrc`)

Yet, I advise against this.  I use `vim` and `zsh` most of the time.  I have `inoremap jk <esc>` in my `vimrc` and I did try using the `bindkey` combination above.  `zsh` waits too long to print `j` when using it, and that annoyed me a lot.

---

#### bash support

`bash` supports `readline` `bind`.  I believe that `bash` can be compiled without `readilne` therefore there may be some rare systems that have bash that do not support `bind` (be  watchful).  To map `jk` to `<esc>` in `bash` you need to do:

```
set -o vi
bind '"jk":"\e"'
```

(yes that's a double level of quoting, it is needed)

Again, this makes typing `j` quite annoying.  But somehow less annoying than the `zsh` solution on my machine (probably the default timeout is shorter).

---

#### Workaround (for non-bash and non-zsh shells)

The reason for remapping the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key is that it lies quite far away on the keyboard, and typing it takes time.  A trick that can be borrowed from the `emacs` guys is to remap <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> since it is a useless key anyway.  `emacs` guys remap it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> but we will remap it to <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Let's use `xev -event keyboard` to check the keycode of <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>:

```
KeyPress event, serial 25, synthetic NO, window 0x1c00001,
    root 0x496, subw 0x0, time 8609026, (764,557), root:(765,576),
    state 0x0, keycode 66 (keysym 0xffe5, Caps_Lock), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

And to check the function of <kbd>Esc</kbd>:

```
KeyPress event, serial 25, synthetic NO, window 0x1c00001,
    root 0x496, subw 0x0, time 9488531, (571,525), root:(572,544),
    state 0x0, keycode 9 (keysym 0xff1b, Escape), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) "
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) "
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Very good, <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> is keycode 66 and <kbd>Esc</kbd>'s function is called "Escape".  Now we can do:

```
# diable caps lock
xmodmap -e "remove lock = Caps_Lock"
# make an Esc key from the keycode 66
xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = Escape"
```

The above **must** be done in this order.  Now every time you hit <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> it works like an <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

---

The tricky part is where to set this.  A file `~/.Xmodmap` with the content:

```
remove lock = Caps_Lock
keycode 66 = Escape
```

Should be respected by most distros (actually display managers, but I'm saying distros for simplicity), but I saw ones that don't respect several `~/X*` files.  For such distros you may try something like:

```
if [ "x" != "x$DISPLAY" ]; then
    xmodmap -e "remove lock = Caps_Lock"
    xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = Escape"
fi
```

In your `.bashrc`.

(In theory that would be better placed in `~/.xinitrc` but if a display manager does not respect `.Xmodmap` it will definitely not respect `~/.xnintrc`.)

Extra note: This only remaps <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to <kbd>Esc</kbd> in a X11 session, therefore the map will only work in terminal emulators.  Actual `tty`'s will not see the map.

References and extra reading:

- [Disabling CapsLock](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75473/how-to-prevent-the-caps-lock-toggle-effect-without-remapping-or-disabling-it)
- [Very detailed answer on how key remapping in X11 works](https://askubuntu.com/questions/296155/how-can-i-remap-keyboard-keys)
- [`.bashrc` vs. `.bash_profile`](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile/)

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. Would you be willing to illustrate the same process except for mapping `jk` instead of `CapsLock`? I have it set on my osx machine; however, I don't have it for the rest of the weekend and I can't remember how I did it :)

Comment: @mbigras - Are you sure you did it in bash?  Bash has no ambiguos maps.  I know of a way of doing it in `zsh`: `bindkey -v; bindkey -s jk \\e`.  But that is something that will come back and bite you back when you need `jk`, because the timer is not configurable and you have no `<leader>` in `zsh`.

Comment: I definitely did it in `zsh` and not `bash`, is it not possible in bash?

Comment: @mbigras - Wait, I was wrong!  Reading `man bash` I found `bind` that work pretty similar to `zsh`'s `bindkey`.  I'll update the answer.  There you go, I'm using `zsh` too much.

Comment: please see edits

Comment: @mbigras - `bind` works in a very similar way to `bindkey`.  You actually can do `bind '"jk":vi-movement-mode'` instead of `bind '"jk":"\e"'`.  But to get all the `vi-*` functions available you will need to dive really deep in the `inputrc` documentation.

Comment: woot woot! :) would you mind prepending your comment to the top of your answer? Then I'd like to accept it

Comment: @mbigras - fair enough.  But I really want to leave the CapsLock stuff there, for some reason `jk` does not annoy me in `vim` but does in the shell (I guess i do not type `jobs` so often in Vim).  Other people may feel the similar way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43976/discussion-between-mbigras-and-grochmal).

Comment: `CapsLock` is not useless. Any language that uses all uppercase as a style for constants benefits from `CapsLock`. Shell variables are often all caps, too. Not to mention a file name may be in all caps (e.g., `README`). I realize filename completion helps with this, but there are so many cases where all caps is used that a `CapsLock` is useful for quickly typing without straining to hold `Shift` or switching which hand presses `Shift`

Comment: @Jason - Hey, this is the Vi SE, In here everyone writes an ALL CAPS word with: "type word"<Esc>viwU :).  No completion needed

Comment: And how would you auto complete a long all caps variable name (like a constant) by typing the first few characters?? I use Ctrl-P and Ctrl-N, but the way my environment is setup, the first few characters must match the case of what I'm auto-completing.

I'm still unconvinced the `CapsLock` is useless (that is, I am unconvinced there is a suitable replacement of equal power and efficiency). I use it everyday... all day long. I'm familiar with <esc>viwU and I use things like this, too.

Comment: I would like to add... that I would love to be convinced! :-) Because if there are things I'm missing then using the `CapsLock` to replace escape would be a nice option. I have not yet found any replacement for the escape key that works across all environments and provides efficiency close to the escape key. Currently I use `jj` in most of my Vi environments. This does not work with Bash in Vi mode, perhaps that's the one environment that I could do something different in since it isn't Vi anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks, for previous answers, I use this in my *~/.zshrc* for vi-like shortcuts in my terminal. I hope it'll help someone.

```
bindkey -v
bindkey 'jk' vi-cmd-mode
```

Comment: I came here looking for answer that works for binding the '^G' key to enter "normal mode" in vi-enabled zsh, and this is the only one that worked.